# Dojo callback never called on iconItem

Tags: dojo, callback, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

This is my constructor:

```
   iconJs =new dojox.mobile.IconItem({label:'', deletable: false, icon:'images/Tile_Toevoegen.png', transition:'slide', class:'klasIcon', url:'views/klappr/addKlas.html', urlTarget:'addKlas', onClick:function(){alert("test onclick");} , callback: function(){alert("test callback");}});
```

When I click on the iconItem, the alert "test onclick" works.
But I need the callbackfunction to work.

In the iconItem guide:

```
    **callback**    
    Function String     
    A callback function that is called when the transition has been finished. A function reference, or name of a function in context.
```

The alert "test callback" needs to be called when the transition is done, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce with Dojo 1.9.1. In addition to item.callback, there is also item.onOpen which could be helpful, however none of them gets called in this case. 
I think this is a Dojo Mobile bug and I suggest that you enter a ticket at https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org .